# SQLite Database Java Application Using Eclipse

Tags: java, sqlite

Hello guys I have create a small java application for desktop that  simple logs data into an sqllite database. The jar files work well on the computer that was built, but, when I distributed on other windows pc it display the message that goes like this

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.sqlite.jdbc

and besides this, only the main login window shows without granting access to the application. The jar file works fine on the pc that it was built on. But not in others computers.
 Is there a configuration that it must be done so the application can be distributed without errors. any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to include the path to the sqlite.jdbc.jar when you run it (something like java --classpath sqlitejdbcjar project)

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. this is the code I set up on the conncetion class....

Comment: public class sqlConnection {
 
 Connection conn=null;
 
 public static Connection dbConnector()
 {
  try{
   Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
   Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\USUARIO\\Documents\\workspace\\School2015.sqlite");
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "BIENVENIDO! Estás Conectado");
   return conn;
     }catch (Exception e)
     {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   return null;
     }

 }
}

Comment: What do you mean when you say include the path... where to include the path.. do  you mean the path  on the above code. This apth wont be recognized in another computer, I guess I have to change it right. Please give more info....

Comment: I understood....now...the path I have in the code above is not recognized on other pcs I get messag ethat says

Comment: jdbc sqlite exception: path does not exist and that referring to is the one on the above code

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1)download latest jar for sqlite https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads

2)incase you are using eclipse ,put your jar in web-inf/lib/

3)check class loader:  Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

4) path of Sqlite file
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:\example\demo.sqlite");

Comment: I already have download the latest  jar, I am using eclipse and the jar is already include in a resources folder as well as in the referenced library in eclipse.. i am thjinking the issue is in the path that is not regognized in other computer..please share more info with me thank you in advance

Comment: you think it may be that taking the desktop application to an older version of windows might be issue..since I made the application in 64 bits windows 7 and I tried using it in 32 bits xp.

Comment: classnotfound exception is mainly caused becoz of wrong jar files or inproper connection string,so i suggest you to post your code snippet